# updating $scope value on $rootScope.$on doesnt update DOM (UI)

Tags: angularjs

What i'm trying to do is update the percentage value (of data downloaded) which i received from service. I am calling $emit to update the controller and in turn value on $scope

```
$rootScope.$emit('event:activityWithResults', results);
```

and in my controller I am doing this

```
$rootScope.$on('event:activityWithResults', function (event, results){
  $scope.percentage = $scope.percentage || {};
  $scope.percentage.value = results.percentageComplete + "%";
  $log.debug("$scope.percentage:" + JSON.stringify($scope.percentage));
});
```

I do see in the logs that value on $scope is being updated on interval (I am not calling $emit for every change but regular interval of say 4 or more percentage of data downloaded. In my html I am simply showing this value
        {{percentage.value}}
But this value doesn't update on UI but it updates only once or twice.

What is wrong here?

Comment: from where you are `$emit` the event? Is it from any `jQuery` listener? If yes then  you need to run digest cycle to udpate the Angular DOM by using `$apply()`

Comment: No its from angular service (same module) but the service is basically a file downloader

Comment: Could you please add the code from where you are `emitting` the event

Comment: `code` eventDispatcher.activityWithResults = function (progressResult){
  if (progressResult.lengthComputable){
   var percentageComplete = Math.round(100 * progressResult.loaded / progressResult.total);
   if (Math.abs(percentageComplete - downloadPercentage) >= 4 ){
    downloadPercentage = percentageComplete;
    var results = {
     percentageComplete: angular.copy(percentageComplete)
    };
    $rootScope.$emit('event:activityWithResults', results);
   }
  }
 }; `code`

Comment: Is the file downloader an asyn activity outside angular context? if so you will have to manually trigger the digest cycle with `$rootScope.$apply` or `digest` and since manual invocation is recommended to be at the top of the call stack you should do it in the service after emit operation.

Comment: Please update the code in the question and what is `eventDispatcher`, i believe this could well be one of many duplicates that needs scope.apply. :)

Comment: @PSL thats what I asked..we need a code who is actual initiator of the event..must be some event which is out of angular context,,

Comment: Awesome yes $digest() is what i missed! Thank you PSL it worked. I  actually tried the approach updating value on non scope variable inside Controller $rootScop.$on and then use that variable in  $scope.$watch and called $apply but it didnt work. Calling digest makes sense